# Minimal presentation of non-abelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p^2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, p-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $H$ be the non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p^2$. A presentation of $H$ is given by

$$H=\langle a,b \mid a^{p^2}=1,b^p=1,[a,b]=a^p \rangle. $$

How do I find a presentation with $2$ generators and $2$ relations (if it exists)? I played around with the relations and couldn't see how any two relations imply the third and I tried using different genrators.

Motivation: Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and let $d(G)$ be the minimal number of generators of $G$. Let $R(G)$ and $r(G)$ be the minimal number of relations needed to present $G$ as an abstract and pro-$p$ group respectively. It is always true that $R(G)\geq r(G)$ and I think there is no known example for $G$ such that $R(G)>r(G)$. Since in this case I know that $r(H)=2$, I expect such a presentation to exist.

Comment: One can compute the Schur multiplier $H_2(G)$. Then the conjecture is that every $d$-generator finite $p$-group should have a presentation with $d+rk(H_2(G))$  relations.

Comment: The Schur multiplier $M(G)=H_2(G)$ is trivial for both nonabelian groups of order $p^3$, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0982.pdf). So $H$ should have a $2$-generator presentation with $2$ relations.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have seen that paper, that's how I know that $r(H)=2$. Since in general $r(G)-d(G)= dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} M(G)[p]$.

Comment: Each of the relations is required, at least for $p=3$. As in, if I delete one I get a different group. So if two relations is possible, they have to not be a subset of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:
$$\langle a,b\mid a^{p^2}=b^p,[a,b]=a^p\rangle$$

Since $(1+p)^p\equiv 1+p^2\pmod{p^3}$ and $a=b^pab^{-p}=a^{(1+p)^p}$, we have $a^{p^2}=1$.

Comment: How can I see that in your presentation $a^{p^2}=b^p=1$?

Comment: I added an argument. Perhaps not the easiest.

Comment: If you know  that $H$ has trivial multiplier, then it follows easily because $a^{p^2} \in Z(G) \cap [G,G]$ (where $G$ is the group defined by the presentation).

Comment: I don't understand why $b^pab^{-p}=a^{(1+p)^p}$, the rest is clear.

Comment: $bab^{-1}=a^{1+p}$, $b^2ab^{-2}=ba^{1+p}b^{-1}=(bab^{-1})^{1+p}=a^{(1+p)^2}$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you, this is great